# registering Bundle to symfony kernel

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

Instead of Using composer I download zip file of a bundle and extract this bundle to my symfony project. I change all relative address for example I change all `namespace Trsteel\CkeditorBundle;` to `namespace Acme\TrsteelCkeditorBundle;` for doing this I searched the downloaded directory for every `Trsteel\CkeditorBundle` and change all of them to Acme\TrsteelCkeditorBundle now when I want to use this Bundle on my project I register this bundle to my `appKernel.php` of symfony project But I reached this error

> Error: Class 'Acme\TrsteelCkeditorBundle\TrsteelCkeditorBundle' not found in /Users/kingkong/Documents/workspace/dev/Project/SRC/app/AppKernel.php line 45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File names should be the same as namespace structure, capitalization may be an issue, so check that.

You may want to place the bundle in this way - "Acme\Trsteel\CkeditorBundle\CkeditorBundle"

Comment: I checked this more than 10 times by the way I solved my problem by this way. first use composer to create this bundle on my vendor after that I change the bundle to my customization and using the created routing of composer just change it to my new route.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have actually changed the folder structure from Trsteel\CkeditorBundle to Acme\TrsteelCkeditorBundle. And also check your routing files as well. (I assume you have done the routing part as the error won't say that it can't get to that location.)

Cheers!

Comment: Yes I double checked and changed Trsteel\CkeditorBundle to Acme\TrsteelCkeditorBundle. Error is not related to routing system. When symfony kernel want to add this bundle symfony give me this error.